# How can I overcome my ISP's DNS redirection when DoH is blocked?

Tags: dns, isp

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265125/can-your-isp-pull-off-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-over-unencrypted-dns).

My ISP is apparently trying to redirect my DNS requests. When I visit some sites, my traffic is redirected to other IPs and not the intended site.

I tried DoH, but my ISP blocks DoH.

And even when I set my primary and alternative DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, it does not help and I get redirected.

So, as a client of this ISP, besides changing my ISP or using a VPN, because the ISP blocks VPNs, what other methods can I use to overcome their redirection of my DNS requests?

Comment: @schroeder Well, the reason that I am rejecting VPNs is because VPN protocols and famous VPN tools are also blocked. SSH tunneling is allowed though. I will edit my post to add it as an additional detail.

Comment: Yeah, you are really stuck. I can't think of a way around this that would not require some custom tunneling to a VPS.

Comment: @schroeder I do have a VPS, fortunately. I use it for creating a local socks5 proxy and it works well, as long as my DNS requests are resolved correctly.

Comment: "I tried DoH, but my ISP blocks DoH." How? DoH uses port 443, exactly like HTTPS. It is not easy to filter it out, besides filtering on the destination IP address. Which ones did you try? See https://dnsprivacy.org/public_resolvers/ for a list of examples.

Comment: " I use it for creating a local socks5 proxy and it works well," You can tunnel DNS queries in a socks tunnel. Browsers have that option.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have tried CloudFlare, Google, NextDNS, OpenNIC, even Yandex, etc. None of them worked. I had linked an article in my original question that explained how it's possible to detect using DoH even though HTTPS is encrypted. Yeah, I tried tunneling DNS queries in the socks tunnel in FireFox but I don't know how to do that system wide. And I don't know how secure that is exactly. I guess it depends on the security of the VPS. Right?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek the DoH blocking is a conclusion from the previous question linked.

Comment: @schroeder That doesn't explain what was attempted exactly and hence how filtering is supposedly happening. There is nothing about DOH in associated question (only in comments)

Comment: "I have tried CloudFlare, Google, NextDNS, OpenNIC, even Yandex, etc. None of them worked." It may be better to show exactly what you tried (which commands, and which behaviour).

Comment: "I guess it depends on the security of the VPS. Right?". Yes, obviously no matter where you connect to you are bound by anything happening on it. You have to put your trust in something, but you can decide which something.

Comment: "Yeah, I tried tunneling DNS queries in the socks tunnel in FireFox but I don't know how to do that system wide." There seems to be various solutions, from a quick search: https://github.com/jtRIPper/dns-tcp-socks-proxy or https://github.com/darkk/redsocks. No guarantees how much you can trust those :-)

Comment: Try https://dnsprivacy.org/dns_privacy_daemon_-_stubby/ ; It is pretty hard on trying to avoid interferences. It is DOT instead of DOH, but DOT can/may be even more and more easily filtered as using its own port.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I understand, but that's the context for this question's assumption

Comment: Can't you use something like `unbound` on your VPS to implement DoH yourself? https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/topics/privacy/dns-over-https.html

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the question **and** the comments, it seems you **are** definitely stuck, perhaps *ultimately*.

Judging from the question, it seems your ISP is active at preventing you from using your own DNS.

DoH is not easy to detect, as it implies establishing an `https` session to an IP address. Your ISP may only know a list of major DoH providers (which are blocked at rules level) or perform MiTM to block DoH queries.

Final options, that go into the scope of VPNs, include SSH bridging to a VPS and Tor.

**But your ISP may be, or become, active at blocking them.**

Comment: I'm quite baffled by the fact that all DoH providers use a dedicated (and obvious) host name such as "https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query" instead of using an existing one such as "http://www.cloudfare.com/doh/mozilla/dns-query". This makes it tragically easy to block based on SNI or initial DNS requests, is it not? The one we were running in LDN (but is now closed) was served from the main website host name (see https://ldn-fai.net/serveur-dns-recursif-ouvert/).

Comment: @ysdx For that specific example I believe it is just to discrimate between traffic used by the browser "automatically" once DoH is enabled, from other traffic.

Comment: "Your ISP may only know a list of major DoH providers " I still did not see anywhere in the question a solid proof of that, with actual examples.

Answer (score 1):

### Warning

First you, should be aware that DoH does not provide a perfect privacy. If you are worried because some state actor might be monitoring your communications, DoH might not be enough:

- the host name you are talking to is still sent in plaintext in the TLS SNI field (this might change in the future);
- the IP address of the machines you are talking to are still sent in plaintext as well.

This might be used to:

- track the sites you are browsing to or more generally the servers you are communicating with;
- block some of them.

If you are worried about this, DoH is not enough!

Solutions might include:

- a SOCKS-over-SSH proxy (with name resolution going through the proxy);
- a proper robust trusted VPN;
- Torbrowser.

See for example [Bellingcat is Banned in Russia. Here’s How to Beat the Block](https://www.bellingcat.com/resources/2022/04/22/how-to-beat-russias-block-on-bellingcat/) for some consideations in this regard.

### Checking whether and howd is blocked

The first thing to do is check if DoH is really blocked and how.

I'm going to take https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query in this example.

For me it seems to be responding OK:

```
$ curl --doh-url https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query https://www.example.com/
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...
```

You could try to launch this command. It this fails enabling verbose output might be useful in order to understand what went wrong:

```
$ curl -vv --doh-url https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query https://www.example.com/
```

This might be enough to see what went wrong. The following subsections provide some instructions in order to test the different phases.

#### Checking (initial) DoH server name resolution

First, we can try to resolve the address of the DoH server:

```
$ dig +short cloudflare-dns.com
104.16.248.249
104.16.249.249
```

Possibilities:

- If you do not have any IP address, at this point your initial (unprotected) DNS request for "cloudflare-dns.com" might be blocked.
- If you have some answer but this is not the same IP I have, this might be normal (or it might be a spoofed DNS response containing a malicious IP address).

#### Using the DoH resolver directly

Now let's try to use use this DoH server in order to resolve [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I'm getting some binary response such as:

```
$ curl https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?dns=AAABAAABAAAAAAAAA3d3dwdleGFtcGxlA2NvbQAAAQAB -D- -o-
HTTP/2 200 
server: cloudflare
date: Fri, 30 Sep 2022 15:19:33 GMT
content-type: application/dns-message
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 49
cf-ray: 752defff4c52d4f6-CDG

��wwwexamplecom�
                ?�]��"
```

Alternatively, you can try to resolve this URL directly from your browser.

If something went wrong, you might want to use the verbose mode (`curl -v`, `curl -vv`) in order to have more information.

Possibilities:

- you cannot establish a connection to this server at the TCP layer, this might mean that you are blocked at the IP/TCP layer;
- you have some TLS error (bad certificate, etc.), this might mean that someone is attempting a man-in-the-middle attack on the connection (possibly based on the SNI field);
- you get a non 200 answer which might mean there something not working;
- you get a 200 answer with some binary data with `application/dns-message`

If you received an answer, you can store it to a file with:

```
$ curl https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?dns=AAABAAABAAAAAAAAA3d3dwdleGFtcGxlA2NvbQAAAQAB -o answer.dns
```

And now you can parse it with Scapy:

```
$ python3 -c 'import scapy.layers.dns; print(repr(scapy.layers.dns.DNS(open("answer.dns", "rb").read())))'
<DNS  id=0 qr=1 opcode=QUERY aa=0 tc=0 rd=1 ra=1 z=0 ad=0 cd=0 rcode=ok qdcount=1 ancount=1 nscount=0 arcount=0 qd=<DNSQR  qname='www.example.com.' qtype=A qclass=IN |> an=<DNSRR  rrname='www.example.com.' type=A rclass=IN ttl=76059 rdlen=None rdata=93.184.216.34 |> ns=None ar=None |>
```

The `an` section lists the different ANSWERS I got in the DNS response:
I got the address 93.184.216.34 which is the IP address of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Possibilities:

- you might get an incorrect answer, this might mean that an attacker has managed to successfully man-in-the-middle your communication with the DoH server (which means that your machine is somehow compromised);
- you might get the correct answer.

### Mitigations

If the DoH provider is blocked at the (initial) name resolution step, you could add a static entry in your `hosts` file in order to statically associate its host name with its IP address.

...

Answer (score 1):

To address the actual question (the other answers about how it shouldn't be easy for an ISP to block DoH completely are also relevant):

You tunnel DNS through another protocol. A simple example would be a VPN like using a openvpn Tunnel to some other host and routing the traffic to a DNS server of your choice through the tunnel.

If you don't have someone who can help you (you only need access to DNS, which is very low traffic), you can rent a cheap VPS. Or for a complete solution you could pay one of the many privacy VPN services, which allow to tunnel all your traffic.

These choices, of course, imply that the corresponding tunnel protocols aren't also blocked.

For some, you should also be able to tunnel them through HTTPS or at least port 443. There are even tools to make the webserver decide if the traffic is forwarded to another service like a VPN program or answered by the server depending on the content of the incoming request. The details may be worth another question here.